# New Line in C# Notification (Compact Framework)

Tags: c#, compact-framework, newline, notifications

I'm trying to use a Notification control in a smart device C# project, but I can't seem to get a new line - I have tried using \n, \r\n and System.Environment.NewLine and none of these work - everything is still showing up on a single line in the standard Visual Studio 2008 emulator. How do I get a new line to show up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of plain text have you tried using HTML and < br > as a new line? 
See this for reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.notification.text.aspx

Comment: I spent the last 10 minutes looking for the 'mark as accepted answer' button all over the place, but couldn't find it - Firefox wasn't showing it for some reason. Tried again in Chrome just now and finally found it. Thanks again to Fiur and Thorsten for the speedy responses!

Answer (score 0):

The notification control uses HTML. You can pass entire HTML documents. To insert newlines, just use < br >. You may even add forms and stuff to allow user input!

Comment: Yup, that did the trick. Using HTML syntax to create forms sounds pretty out there but for now I'm just happy to have a new line :)